# which language is more suitable for computer graphics

Tags: java, c, graphics

Which language among C or Java will be more suitable for Computer Graphics.In general what would be the characteristics of a computer language that would make it more suitable for Computer Graphics?

Comment: Clear answer? It depends. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: In general i want to perform a lot of pixel manipulation operations.

Comment: Gaming or desktop illustration?

Comment: Are you writing high computation graphics? Do you need to be able to access the GPU? You should probably go with a C language.

Comment: 9 out of 9 people will tell you that C++ has better performance. But don't forget that Minecraft was made in Java.

Comment: Processing, which is based on Java.

Comment: processing is faster in java @nickecarlo?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Lee i want to use it for desktop illustrations

Comment: @user1946152 What do you mean by "faster"? Its easier to implement graphics in Processing as its main purpose is to visualize data and art on computers. Check it out here: http://www.processing.org/

Comment: oh sorry did not know that processing is a language.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve. In general it's the available libraries for the language, not the language itself, that really matters.

Comment: okay but in general C codes would be more faster than java codes,right?

Comment: At least C is not slower. I understand smart algorithms are more important than any overhead added by using java. But C gets you one step closer to the hardware, so if you really want to optimize and have full control I believe C would be a natural choice. But I am not a graphics programmer, so my knowledge about these things are only superficial.

Answer (score 0):

Most windows games are created in C++ with DirectX. If you want to make a 3D animation, you have to learn sin cos, ...

Comment: Nope. Most games for **Windows** are made in C++ with DirectX. Games made for Android, iOS, PS3, Wii and Wii U are mostly made with pure C++ or C++ like languages, but there's no DirectX in those worlds.

Comment: @Renan Sry, Im not a mobile developer

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: better?

Comment: +1 just for putting up with hair splitters. And Xbox is not Windows. Xbox games are also developed with DirectX.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: now?

Comment: @Hydroid I think that is clearer and has more truth to it.

Answer (score 0):

The language for computer graphics determines on what you are trying to do. When it comes to 3d, Java has Java3D which is an API that is much easier for an OOP kind of design; however, c/c++ have OpenGL, which is useful for things like 3D, which is much better with graphics, and the least amount of time it takes to render, and load. Even though this is, it is much more difficult within the coding because it is a lot more complex. Hope this helps!